# I am using .asx link in the Uri.parse function and it is not working

Tags: android, parsing, uri

Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://www.munichshardesthits.com/ondem/timeless%20rock.asx");

I am using .asx link in the parse function and it is not working.
Basically,I want to make .asx link work here.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT*

It may be more likely that it does not support the space character which is what '%20' escapes.

A valid Uri cannot contain the '%' character.

See '2.4.3. Excluded US-ASCII Characters' here:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396

Comment: This %20 space character works well with the mp3 format.Then how to solve the issue?

Comment: This format is also not running...
http://www.wxyc.org/files/streams/wxyc-mp3.m3u

Comment: You need to fully specify the scheme along with most probably two forward slashes. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax